# ImageIO.write слишком медленный

Tags: java

```
BufferedImage image = r.createScreenCapture(
   new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));       //1
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();             //2
ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", baos);                                    //3
```

Хочу реализовать передачу видео по UDP(тут, очевидно, только получение картинки). Строка №3 преобразует картинку очень медленно. Строки №1,2 работают сравнительно быстро. №3 в несколько раз медленнее. Как можно это исправить(может по-другому брать скрин и получать массив байтов. Или может есть легкий способ отправлять картинку по сокетам)? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: ос какая у Вас?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , win 10. А это влияет на скорость преобразования картинки в bytearray?

Comment: на linux и openjdk6 было в 4 раза медленне чем на винде и hotspot jdk 6, правда очень давно

Comment: в итоге все это мутировало в гибрид jni-ffmpeg